# bash script collecting filenames seems to get confused by spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, whitespace

I'm trying to build a script that lists all the zip files in a set of directories, with some filters and get it to spit them out to file but when a filename has a space in it it seems to appear on a new line.

This list will eventually be used as an input to tar to gzip all the zip files, script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f set1.txt

rm -f set2.txt

for line in $(find /home -type d -name assets ;); 

do 

    echo $line >> set1.txt

    for line in $(find $line -type f -name \*.zip -mtime +2  ;);

    do

        echo \"$line\"  >> set2.txt     

    done;
```

This works as expected until you get a space in a filename then set2.txt contains entries like this:

```
"/home/xxxxxx/oldwebroot/htdocs/upload/assets/jobbags/rbjbCost"

"in"

"use"

"sept"

"2010.zip"
```

Does anyone know how I can get it to keep these filenames with spaces in in a single line with the whole lot wrapped in one set of quotes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to loop over a set of files located via `find` is with a while read construct, thus:

```
while IFS= read -r  -d '' line ; do
    echo "$line" >> set1.txt
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file ; do
            printf '"%s"\n' "$file" >> set2.txt
    done < <(find "$line" -type f -name \*.zip -mtime +2 -print0)
done < <(find /home -type d -name assets -print0)
```

For clarity I have given the inner loop variable a different name.

If you didn't have `bash` you'd have to issue the `find` command separately and redirect the output to a file, then read the file with `while read ; do .. done < filename`.

Note that each expansion of each variable is double-quoted. This is necessary.

Note also, however, that for what you want you can simply use the `-printf` switch to `find`, if you have GNU `find`.

```
find /home -type f -path '*/assets/*.zip' -mtime +2 -printf '"%p"\n' > set2.txt
```

Although, as @sarnold notes, this is not safe.

Comment: brilliant, thanks, that's got the job done nicely. Thankyou for posting such a complete solution, I'll read up on "read" if you'll pardon the pun.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be executing your `tar(1)` command through some other mechanism; the `find(1)` program supports a `-print0` option to request ASCII `NUL`-separated filename output, and the `xargs(1)` program supports a `-0` option to tell it that the input is separated by ASCII `NUL` characters. (Since `NUL` is the only character that is not allowed in filenames, this is the only way to get *reliable* filename handling.)

Simply using the `-print0` and `-0` options will *help* but this still leaves the script open to another problem -- `xargs(1)` might decide to execute the `tar(1)` command two, three, or more times, depending upon its input. The *last* execution is the one that will "win", and the data from earlier invocations will be lost for ever. (This is useless as a backup.)

So you should also look into adding the `--concatenate` command line option to `tar(1)`, too, so that it will *add* to the archive. It might make sense to perform the compression *after* all the files have been added, via `gzip(1)` or `bzip2(1)`. (This does mean you need to *remove* the archive before a "fresh run" of this script.)

Comment: the -print0 option still generates the same list with the whitespace issue, I've not really got to the tar stage, hence the comment but thanks for the tips on that next bit. What I need is a modification to the find line I think that gives me a single line in set2.txt, enclosed by double quotes, that just has one line per file, even if the filename has spaces in it.

Comment: But what if your filenames also have quotes? Or newlines? The _only_ mechanism that is safe to use in shell scripts is to combine `find(1)`'s `-print0` and `xargs(1)`'s `-0` options. That way, characters don't matter. (I'd even skip the `set2.txt` file unless you've got a compelling reason for it to exist.)